# How to query all active / online users?

Tags: getstream-io

According to the documentation, it seems that one needs to indicate the users list that we want to query e.g.:

```
const response = await client.queryUsers({ id: { $in: ['john', 'jack', 'jessie'] } });
```

In this example, we need to indicate that we want the details of these 3 users. Is there a way to query all active users instead of passing an array of `ids` / `names`?

I tried:

```
const response = await client.queryUsers(
    { presence: true },
);
```

But it returned an empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`presence: true` registers your client to presence events (online/offline).

There is no support to get this in one go. Also, beware if user is hidden, the user is requesting this information might not be able to see the real online users.

Current recommendation is to get channel with `state: true` and iterate your members and also setting `presence: true`, you will be notified by status changes.

Comment: Would this solution be ideal if e.g. we have a thousand chat participants? Means I need to first retrieve the list of users from our server and then pass that array of user ids to queryUsers?

Comment: Yes, not ideal but required right now. I raised a ticket to implement, I will update here when it's done.

Comment: What actually determines user presence? is it when user starts watching or when user has been set via `setUser`? or something else?

Comment: When user starts watching. https://getstream.io/chat/docs/presence_format/?language=js&q=presence#listening_to_presence_changes if something is missing in the docs, you can comment on the spot