# query friends who are online with getstream.io

Tags: getstream-io

What is the best way to retrieve a user's online friends when each user has around 100 friends on average?

1. According to [the document](https://getstream.io/chat/docs/flutter-dart/query_users/?language=dart), I can query x number of users with their ids. If I can query 100 users at a time, I should do this. I wasn't able to find the maximum number of users per query.
2. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60947417/13161301) seems to suggest that I can create a hidden channel for each user with the user's friends and query the channel to see who's online. What is the maximum number of members per channel?

What should I do if each user has around 1000 friends on average.